# Sharing Screenshot on Android. Shares the same image every time

Tags: android, image, file, screenshot, sharing

I have created a function that takes a screenshot, saves it in a temporary file of the type .jpeg, and then allows users to share it on facebook or bluetooth. Here is my share function:

```
public Bitmap Share(View v) {
    // Sound
    soundPool.play(button_sound, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);

    // Image
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, ostream);
        ostream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Share
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    String filel = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg";
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filel));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    return bitmap;
}
```

My problem is that it takes the screenshot, but then always shares the same screenshot over and over when I try to share a new one. When i check using the file manager, the image is different. SO I don't know what's causing that.

Thank you very much for you time.

Comment: have you noticed that name of newly created file is same as old one, why not you generate a random file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `file.createNewFile()` only works when the file does not exist. It doesn't throw any exceptions when failed, it only returns `true` for success and `false` for fails,

Same is true for `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, ostream);` . This methods also doesn't throw any exceptions when failed, and only returns `true` for success and `false` for fails,

I don't know if it it causing the error but you might want to look into that. You might try for example to delete the file first when it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please invalidated() your view before getBitmap

look like:

```
v.inValidated(); 
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```